# Self-managed IRA account brokerage as an HSA?

Tags: united-states, ira, hsa

Most specific than [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/where-are-good-places-to-go-for-an-hsa-in-the-united-states), I'm desperately seeking a TD Ameritrade or E-Trade type online brokerage that offers self managed HSAs to accompany an HDHP.  I cannot find one.

Is there another key word that I should be looking for?  Can *any* IRA be used as an HSA and I just don't realize it, assuming I do the right paperwork?

If there are no such options, are there legal reason why there cannot be?  Are there financial disincentives making such offerings unappealing to brokerages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [Directory of HSA Administrators](http://www.hsa-administrators.com/home-a-z.htm)

A google of HSA administrators turns up quite a list. These accounts are separate from IRAs, and an IRA can't substitute. The HSA is required to have the HDHP and the insurer running it should be offering you the linked HSA partners as they are closely tied.

Comment: Thanks for this link.  This is very helpful.  "HSA Administrators" is a good search term.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the "accepted answer." There's a certain knack to getting what you want on Google, but it's worth the effort, as over time you'll learn to get pretty fast answers. Here the trick was the word "Administrator." – JoeTaxpayer